# Is it legit to down-vote good question that seems to be illegal?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Is it legit to downvote a question, which content is *good* and might be helpful for other people, but the content seems to be used for illegal stuff in the question case?

Comment: In case of doubt, flag it for moderator attention. Also, consider legality may be dependent on location.

Comment: @mirabilos good point, especially: `Also, consider legality may be dependent on location.`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do with such posts is flag it. If you don't think the question is helpful from your point of view (and "illegal" goes much further than "not useful" in my opinion), you are free to cast a down-vote. It is totally up to you.

The most downvoted question (as far as I know) is this one on Stack Overflow: [How to send 100,000 emails weekly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3905734/993547) This is a border-line 'how-to-spam' question. It might be useful to "you", as a spammer, but illegal in some countries. If you want to downvote such a question, go ahead.

You can always let such things double-check by a moderator by flagging it.

Comment: Good one, thank you!